# What is the best way to use the json postgresql datatype via the query builder in CakePHP?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, cakephp

I haven't found a way to use postgresql's json operators, `->`, `->>`, etc.

I expected to be able to use them in this sort of way:

`$this->MyModel->find('all', array('conditions'=>array("jsonfield->'key'"=>"value")`

But it results in an error like:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column MyModel.jsonfield->'key' does not exist LINE 1`

Comment: I can confirm from this issue https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4666 that support for JSON data type out of the box doesn't exist, unfortunately. We use it primarily to add user defined fields to some of our models